# What is the difference between "'pages.apps.PagesConfig'" and "pages"?

Tags: django

It seems there are two ways to register a Django app (say, `pages`) in `INSTALLED_APPS` (in file 'settings.py'):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     pages,                   #option 1
     pages.apps.PagesConfig,  #option 2
]
```

Both seem to work with simple apps. But are there any differences between `pages.apps.PagesConfig` and `pages`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per user @riterix on Reddit who responded to my inquiry:

"The second one gives you the ability to load custom things... Like signals,...

For example you want to load some settings from db after accounts app load when a user logged in through signals.

NB : We used the second method in our project to load currency, metrics,... As a sessions variables based on the user country after he successfully logged in."